# How to find indices of max n elements in array in stable order

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a number and an array:

```
n = 4
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4]
```

I want to find the indices corresponding to the maximal `n` elements of `a` in the reverse order of the element size, and in stable order when the element sizes are equal. The expected output is:

```
[5, 3, 4, 2]
```

This code:

```
a.each_with_index.max(n).map(&:last) 
# => [5, 4, 3, 2]
```

gives the right indices, but changes the order.

Comment: Your example is not very great. The elements you gave in the array can be easily confused with the indices. They look too similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Code**

```
def max_with_order(arr, n)
   arr.each_with_index.max_by(n) { |x,i| [x,-i] }.map(&:last)
end
```

**Examples**

```
a = [0,1,2,3,3,4]

max_with_order(a, 1)  #=> [5]
max_with_order(a, 2)  #=> [5, 3]
max_with_order(a, 3)  #=> [5, 3, 4]
max_with_order(a, 4)  #=> [5, 3, 4, 2]
max_with_order(a, 5)  #=> [5, 3, 4, 2, 1]
max_with_order(a, 6)  #=> [5, 3, 4, 2, 1, 0]
```

**Explanation**

For `n = 3` the steps are as follows.

```
b = a.each_with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4]:each_with_index>
```

We can convert `b` to an array to see the (six) values it will generate and pass to the block.

```
b.to_a                
  #=> [[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]]
```

Continuing,

```
c = b.max_by(n) { |x,i| [x,-i] }
  #=> [[4, 5], [3, 3], [3, 4]]
c.map(&:last)
  #=> [5, 3, 4]
```

Note that the elements of `arr` need not be numeric, merely comparable.

Comment: Beautiful. Exactly the answer I came up with.

Comment: While I applaud your, always, thorough answers your original implementation is still referenced in the *Continuing* section but the new implementation (which is much nicer by the way) no longer uses `min_by`

Answer (score 4):

You can supply a block to `max` to make the determination more specific like so

```
a.each_with_index.max(n) do |a,b| 
  if a[0] == b[0] # the numbers are the same
    b[1] <=> a[1] # compare the indexes in reverse
  else
    a[0] <=> b[0] # compare the numbers themselves
  end
end.map(&:last) 
#=> [5,3,4,2]
```

`max` block expects a comparable response e.g. -1,0,1 so in this case we are just saying if the number is the same then compare the indexes in reverse order e.g. `4 <=> 3 #=> -1` the -1 indicates this values is less so that will then be placed after 3

Also to expand on @CarySwoveland's answer (which I am a bit jealous I did not think of), since you only care about returning the indices we could implement as follows without a secondary `map`

```
a.each_index.max_by(n) { |x| [a[x],-x] }
#=> [5,3,4,2]
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland I was inspired

Answer (score 0):

@compsy you wrote **without** changing order, so it would be:

```
a = [0,1,2,3,3,4]
n = a.max
i = 0
a.each do |x|
  break if x == n
  i += 1
end
```

I use variable *i* as index, when *x* (which is the value beeing analized) is equals *n* we use *break* to stop the *each* method conserving the last value of *i* wich corresponds to the position of the max value at the array. Be aware that value of *i* is different by one of the natural position in the array, and tht is because in arrays the first element is 0 not 1.

I *break* the *each* because there is no need to keep checking all the other values of the array after we found the position of the value.

Comment: This does not actually do anything other than potentially changing the value of `i`, dependent on the order of the values in `a`, and the return value will be `[0,1,2,3,3,4]` because `each` will return the `Enumerable` upon completion of the iteration